# "Related List - Single" not available for Asset record detail page in the Experience Builder

Tags: community, community-builder

I have the following issue:

I have a Digital Experience site, with several objects' pages on it.
One of them is Asset.

I wanted to add "**Related List - Single**" component to Asset's record detail page in the community builder, but it's not visible in the components list:

[image: Image of components list with no desired component on it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to go to the Builder Settings (from menu on the left) -> Advanced, and then check "Show all components".

[image: Screenshot of 'Show all components' option]

Apparently, "Related List - Single" is not used too often with the Asset object, and Salesforce decided to hide it. It was not clear to me, as I expected only components that can't be used with the page type, to be hidden, and "Related List - Single" works without any additional configuration, but it's simply how Salesforce decided they want it to be.